# iOs 13 Could not retrieve region info

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am newbie trying to use mapkitview but when I run the app the map does not show on the simulator.I have tried all the necessary solutions but to no avail.I restarted the simulator, did the region settings,Debug and clicked on city run, and also when I open the original map in the iOS simulator it also appears blank.Below is my code and simulator.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code

[image: code]

Please Here is an updated version of my code.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 10000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()
    }


    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }


    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }


    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {
            // Show alert letting the user know they have to turn this on.
        }
    }


    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            centerViewOnUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .denied:
            // Show alert instructing them how to turn on permissions
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            // Show an alert letting them know what's up
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }
    }
}


extension MapScreen: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the `Privacy` in `Info.plist`? Are you checking the `Location Authorization Status`? Please check this on your actual device rather than the simulator.

Comment: Yes Please I did set the Privacy in Info.plist.

Comment: Have you added `CoreLocation`?

Comment: Yes please I have updated my code.

Comment: Check it on a real device.

Comment: Please verify on simulator safari, does your simulator have active internet connection?

Comment: yes please the internet Connection is working on the simulator safari and also the apple original map on the simulator doesn't load, but the other Apps on the simulator does .

Comment: I guess i will have to check it on real device and see.

Comment: Yes finally it works on my phone . Thank you guys very much.